# View Alaskan/East Siberian Side of Arctic in Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have some points plotted on a NorthPolarStero map in Cartopy using the following code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,8),  subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()})

ax.scatter([x[0] for x in max_coords[:-1]],
           [x[1] for x in max_coords[:-1]],
           color='k',
           s=50,
           marker='x',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),zorder=5,
           label='BSH Center 1980-2020')

ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 90, 66], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, edgecolor='black',zorder=1)

ax.legend(fontsize='x-large')
```

[image]

But I would actually like to plot just the top half of this image, like this:

[image]

If I change the ```ax.set_extent`` line to either:

`[90, -90, 90, 66]`
or
`[-90, 90, 90, 66]`

It just gives me the bottom half of the plot, like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to get the top half? I have also tried setting the `central_longitude` keyword of the NorthPolarStereo line to +/- 180, but it just shows the wrong half upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set extents for plotting the required area, you should use the coordinates of the projection in use `ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()`. The relevant code you need is: –

```
ax.set_extent([-2.633e+06, 2.696e+06, -6e+04, 2.9e+06], crs=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
```

and you should get the plot similar to this:

[image: nps_top]

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any advice on how I can get rid of the 60W & 60E labels at the bottom of the figure?

Comment: Nevermind - got it with:

gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(np.concatenate([np.arange(-180,-89,15),np.arange(90,181,15)]))

Comment: There is a possible workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64019387/specify-the-lat-lon-label-location-in-cartopy-remove-at-some-sides but for the top edge. Can be altered to manipulate the bottom.